# Android Service Exception - Permission denied missing INTERNET permission

Tags: android, exception, permissions, android-permissions

I have stumbled upon a problem I just can't seem to fix.

2 scenarios, in the first a user clicks a button which fires a method in `MainActivity` to make a web request. This works, no problem at all.

In the second scenario I want to make this request automatically in a service running in the background, as soon as the code moves into the Service, it makes a permission exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
```

I can start up the service perfectly fine, but if I move any network requests into the service then I get into permission problems.

I already have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

I also do realtime permission checking (SDK 23+) in my MainActivity before starting the service, but this seems to have no effect on the permissions that the service gets.

Any ideas?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="domain">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name="domain.RemoteCommunicationService"
        android:isolatedProcess="true"
        android:exported="true">
    </service>
    <receiver android:name="domain.RemoteServiceRestartReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="domain.RemoteServiceRestart"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="domain.RemoteCommunicationService$RemoteCommunicationReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="domain.RemoteCommunication.ToggleLight"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: show your manifest file

Comment: @Jonas D post your manifest and what is your sdk if its 23 or up you might need run-time perms

Comment: Added manifest file - the issue only occurs in the RemoteCommuincationService, not in my Main activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have use `isolateProcess` to `true`. Read what docs has to say:

> If set to true, this service will run under a special process that is isolated from the rest of the system and has no permissions of its own. The only communication with it is through the Service API (binding and starting).

Comment: omfg... I have spent hours trying to find the solution... THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: you are welcome ... and dont forget to accept if it solved your problem

Comment: I will in a few minutes when the option becomes available :)